# No such file or directory (path error)

Tags: php

Well, the structure of site is simple:

## site.com

1. '`config`' folder

   - config.php
   - cesar.php
2. '`login`' folder

   - index.php
3. index.php

---

Config.php:

```
include_once '../config/cesar.php';
```

At `site.com/index.php`:

```
Warning: include_once(../config/cesar.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

At `site.com/login/index.php` everything is OK.

---

If I will remove one dot (./config/cesar.php), main index will become OK and login page will get the error.
How to make both codes work?

Comment: **..** means going back to the directory. Since both **config.php AND cesar.php** are both in the same folder no need to put **..** and just call **include_once '/config/cesar.php';**

Comment: @CamiloGo, with /config/cesar.php gets the error on login page.

Comment: **include_once '../config/cesar.php';** that is only for 'login' folder since you are accessing index.php and cesar.php is in another folder. It needs to go up the directory to find the folder it's in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `..` in your path are used to go up a directory because of that the file won't exist where you are looking for it.

If you update it to be `include_once 'config/cesar.php';` it should work since that will allow it to go down into the config directory rather than try to find a directory with the name of config 1 level above where index.php is located.

`./` works since `.` is the notation for the current directory.

To answer your question, it wouldn't be possible to have the code work by using a relative path since both the files are in different locations on the server in relation to the one you want to include. If you want to have something that does then you will need to use an absolute path rather than the relative path. This would be something like `/path/to/webdirectory/site.com/path/to/file/config.php` (i.e. `/home/charles/websites/site.com/config/config.php`) in *nix and `C:\path\to\webdirectory\site.com\path\to\file\config.php` on windows.

In PHP you should be able to get the absolute path in a dynamic way by using the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable. Ex: `include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config/cesar.php';`

Comment: with config/cesar.php also gets the error on login page

Comment: @EdgarCooper Sorry, I was in the middle of editing my answer after I realized that you were using the same line of code in both files. It is possible, you just need to use an absolute path rather than a relative one.

Comment: @EdgarCooper I updated my answer again with a way to make the include absolute without being hard coded to the server. Try `include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'config/cesar.php';` If that doesn't work then what does the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` variable give you? Does it go directly to the site.com folder or something else? It should return the documentroot as defined in the web server config.

Comment: thanks a lot! It works, but with slash before config/...php

Comment: @EdgarCooper Awesome! I updated the answer so the slash is included now for anybody in the future. It may be dependent on the web host config though.

Answer (score -1):

> `Warning: include_once(../config/cesar.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

I ran into a similar problem once. You need to remember that `(./config/xxx.php)` and `(config/xxx.php)` mean the same thing but `(../config/xxx.php)` will go up a directory and find the config folder and xxx.php file in it.

You can also use `$base_url` as a prepend string to all your paths to make it clean. Where:

```
$base_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Then replace your paths like

```
../config/xxx.php
```

with

```
$base_url.'/config/xxx.php'
```

Comment: This may not work everywhere, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is a safer method since you aren't including remote files. For an include going over HTTP or FTP you have to have specific settings enabled in your php.ini - See http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php