# Is it possible to put my connection file in the Root Directory and fetch data from sub directories?

Tags: php, mysql

Every-time I have to place my `connection.php` file into my sub-folders along with index file. I failed to understand why do I have to put my connection file every-time inside my sub-folders.

I have also tried putting my connection file in the root folder, and include it by it's path name `/connection.php` but it doesn't fetch Mysql data.

It doesn't worked with `require''`, `include''`, `include_once''`

I couldn't found much help on this topic. Isn't there a better way to do this?

**Update:**

File Structure

```
localhost/school/icse/index-icse
```

I have to put my `connect_mysqli.php` in every sub-folder like this

Code:

```
<?php
include'connect_mysqli.php';
$output = '';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM city WHERE state_id = '".$_POST["stateId"]."' ORDER BY city_name";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$output = '<option value="">Select City</option>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $output .= '<option value="'.$row["city_id"].'">'.$row["city_name"].'</option>';
}
echo $output;
?>
```

Thank you!

`conSub` is the folder that contains my connection file `connect_mysqli.php` 
and the 2nd red circle shows we are in this sub-folder now.

Normally it should work. I'm not able to figure out, what's the problem...
I have tried

- `include("/conSub/connect_mysqli.php");`
- `include("conSub/connect_mysqli.php");`
- `include_once("/conSub/connect_mysqli.php");`
- `include_once("conSub/connect_mysqli.php");`
- `require("/conSub/connect_mysqli.php");`
- `require("conSub/connect_mysqli.php");`

Please check this is my Data Structure

[image: directory structure of the project]

Comment: @Rohit Take a look at [No such file or directory (path error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45725833/no-such-file-or-directory-path-error/45725855). It's about the same thing, including a file using the same line of code in multiple scripts that are in different folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check if you have typed corrct name of file.

Other some of possible solution :

If your files `connect_mysqli.php` and index.php( or whatever) are in the same directory, you can use these option

```
include_once("./connect_mysqli.php");
```

or

```
include_once("connect_mysqli.php");
```

If your `connect_mysqli.php` is in `public_html/conSub` and file that need connection is in `school/icse`, then you can use like this

```
include_once("../../conSub/connect_mysqli.php");
```

Or if your public_html dir is root directory then you can use this also

```
include_once("/conSub/connect_mysqli.php"); //only if public_html is root dir
```

Comment: Thanks @manpreet-singh Yes. public_html is the root dir. I have tried include_once("/conSub/connect_mysqli.php"); I will try include_once("../../conSub/connect_mysqli.php"); But before that I think I need to check my .htaccess files as rightly pointed by james-geldart. I haven't checked it a long time now...and that might be the reason if I have /* escaped that folder. I will update this post in some time, if that works or not. Thanks again. :)

Comment: your welcome. If you still doesn't work then try using require and check the errors and use error_reporting();

Comment: oh my god! Silly me. It worked with "../../conSub/connect_mysqli.php" But why it didn't worked when I specified "/conSub/connect_mysqli.php". This is weird. Anyways, thanks much Manpreet!

Comment: but why do you say that @manpreet-singh public_html is not my root directory. If that's the case how come my every '/css', '/js', and '/img' folder respond to it perfectly. It's just in this case that it doesn't work with "/". That's why I asked this question. And it is really weird that it responds to '../../conSub/connect_mysqli.php'  and not to '/conSub/connect_mysqli.php' :(

Comment: No @manpreet-singh. I tested it today. It has nothing to do with .htaccess I have tested it twice  while removing the entire .htaccess file. Any other guess? Have you encountered something similar?

Answer (score 2):

PHP includes will look in the current directory (i.e. the directory of the script that was called), and whatever is defined in the php.ini as the include_path. You can also add to this with `set_include_path()`.

So at some point you are going to need to put in a reference to the base directory within your script, either:

```
set_include_path('/var/www/html/school');
require_once("connect_mysqli.php");
```

or

```
require_once("/var/www/html/school/connect_mysqli.php");
```

Neither is ideal because you are hardcoding the location of your site into the code - it isn't very portable!

Better practice (and what most PHP frameworks do), is to run everything through a single index.php file. Assuming you use Apache you can use mod_rewrite and .htaccess files to make your URLs friendly, e.g.:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then your index.php should have your global includes and some routing logic, as so:

```
require_once "connect_mysqli.php";
if(file_exists($_GET['page'] . '.php') {
  require_once ($_GET['page'] . '.php');
}
else {
  require_once "error.php";
}
```

There are many ways you can improve this, but it will give you the bare bones.

As an aside, in your code you are opening yourself to SQL injection attacks by putting a raw $_POST variable into your database query. It should at the very least be escaped. Please read this: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Thanks @james-geldart I never knew we can do it with .htaccess files also.  I'm familiar with .htaccess files. I will surely try this. Could you please elaborate the last line "^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]"

Comment: yep, that will pass the URL to index.php in the 'page' variable, e.g. /foo/bar will mean $_GET['page'] is '/foo/bar'

Comment: No @james-geldart. I got a Blank page. :( 
I replaced my earlier code:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

To this one:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this if i understand

```
<?php require_once("../../conSub/connect_mysqli.php");?>
```

use require_once and specify your subfolder name with /connection.php
I hope it works

Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there

Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there

Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts there (and so on...)

Comment: Yes it worked with "../../" But why it did'nt worked when "/" root dir is specified. Anyways, thanks Dawud!

Comment: @Rohit. because of the directories. you visit this link for more info. https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/. Please dont forget to accept the answer. You are always welcome.

Comment: Thank you Dawud. I know that. Everything works when you specify "/" root dir be it images folder, be it javascript folder, be it css folder, be it anything specified in root dir (public-html in my case) but failed to understand why it doesn't included '/conSub/connect_mysqli.php'. I guess it doesn't works that way with php files...right?

Comment: @Rohit Like you still dont understant how linking pages work Assuming the you have a folder call website which contain maybe  index page and you have subfolder call consub which contains your connect_mysqli.php. In that case using conSub/connect_mysqli.php is the perfect way because you want to access a file in subfolder. However, if it happens in the other way round like index page in consub and connect_mysqli.php is in the website folder and you want to like the connect_mysqli.php into a sub folder then you have to it in like this" ../connect_mysqli.php" . "../" moves one directory backwards